# Are there any satellites with 435 MHz uplink?

Tags: satellites, uhf

I have a transceiver working in the 435 MHz ham band. I want to test my uplink capability by communicating with satellites operating in this band.

Are there any digital satellites which I can use for this purpose?

Comment: http://oscar.dcarr.org/ might be a good place to start.

Comment: I saw the page. I did not get exactly which satellites from the list are available for uplink in the 435Mhz range.It just mentioned the status of various satellites.

Comment: The page referred to by @MichaelKjörling has moved to: http://www.amsat.org/status/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There certainly have been satellites using 435 MHz uplink: for example, [STRaND-1](https://amsat-uk.org/satellites/telemetry/strand-1/), in which I had some minor involvement, used 435 MHz LSB. I don't believe we had an unencrypted uplink capability, though - however, you may well find hamsats that have.

The satellite went quiet fairly quickly, but if you do manage to receive any telemetry from it - it did wake up again for a while, so this is not impossible - the team and I would be delighted to hear!

Answer (score 2):

From [Amsat UK](http://amsat-uk.org/2015/10/07/fox-1a-launch/):

> Fox-1A frequencies, see [Operating Guide](http://www.amsat.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/FoxOperatingGuide_May2015_Hi.pdf) to set up your rigs memory channels:
>   435.180 MHz FM Uplink 67 Hz CTCSS PL tone required
>   145.980 MHz FM Downlink
>   Note: If your rig has selectable FM filters use the wider filter for 5 kHz deviation 25 kHz channel spacing.